# Acronym package: Handling possessive case (apostrophe s)

Tags: acronyms

How do I handle the possessive form of an acronym using the `acronym` package?

Acronym definition:

```
\begin{acronym}
\acro{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\end{acronym}
```

Usage:

```
The \ac{FBI}'s plan. The \ac{FBI}'s plan.
```

Result:

```
The Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI)'s plan. The FBI's plan.
```

The short form is right, but the long form is wrong.

Comment: What is the correct long form?

Comment: @PaulGaborit With the `glossaries` package, `The \ac{FBI}['s] plan. The \ac{FBI}['s] plan.` would produce "The Federal Bureau of Investigation’s (FBI) plan. The FBI’s plan." I'm not sure if that's the official correct long form, but it looks better than having the apostrophe after the parentheses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a method that defines the command `\acposs` which will expand to *long*'s (*short*) on first use and *short*'s on next use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acposs}[1]{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname AC@\AC@prefix#1\endcsname\AC@used
   \acs{#1}'s%
 \else
   \aclu{#1}'s (\acs{#1})%
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\end{acronym}

The \acposs{FBI} plan. The \acposs{FBI} plan.

\end{document}
```

[image: FBI Federal Bureau of Investigation The Federal Bureau of Investigation’s (FBI) plan. The FBI’s plan.]

If you prefer *long*'s (*short*'s) then use the following definition instead:

```
\newcommand{\acposs}[1]{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname AC@#1\endcsname\AC@used
   \acs{#1}'s%
 \else
   \aclu{#1}'s (\acs{#1}'s)%
 \fi
}
```