# In the LaTex Glossary package, how do you make a possessive acronym?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

How would I make an acronym possessive? I've tried using `\gls{ACR}['s]` but that will just print out "Acronym (ACR)'s".

`main.tex` is typed as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
 \makeglossaries


% acronyms:
\newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{Acronym }

\begin{document}

\gls{ACR}['s]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `acronym` package. Rather than glossaries.

You will need to defined the following method in your preamble:

```latex
\newcommand{\acposs}[1]{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname AC@#1\endcsname\AC@used
   \acs{#1}'s%
 \else
   \aclu{#1}'s (\acs{#1})%
 \fi
}
```

You can then call `\acposs{ACR}` to get *Acronym's (ACR)*.

See my other answer if you want to use the glossaries package (a *much* simpler solution).

Reference: Nicola Talbot at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416637/212801

Answer (score 0):

Add

```latex
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
```

just after `\makeglossaries`.

There may be other acronym styles that work, but I found this style in [the documentation](http://mirror.ufs.ac.za/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#ex:sampleAcr) and can confirm that it works.

EDIT: Acronym style `long-short` also works, and it doesn't introduce small caps, unlike `long-sc-short`.