# acronym package automatic sorting and AC's option

Tags: acronyms

**Update:**

What I wan't to achieve is:

1. have my acronym short and post it with an 's in the text. So f.e. my `\acp{gdr}` gets GDRs  but I want GDR's as result;

(Full: 'As a result of the GDR's political control over the influx of migrants.' )

2. have my table of acronyms autmatically sorted by the alphabet

I am also using the package but I can't find how to achieve AC's (f.e. I have the acro GDR = German Democratic Republic and want to write "The GDR's xyz is very ...") plus I haven't found an option about automatically sorting the list of acronmys. Anybody with solutions? I also looked at the acro package they would have the option to declare my plural. But I am familiar with the other package so I'd like to move on with it.

(Here some example code)

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

\input{VorlageE.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Bibtex File einbinden %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addbibresource{literatur.bib} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Beginn des Dokuments  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section*{List of acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of acronyms}%
\markboth{List of acronyms}{List of acronyms}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abkürzungen %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{acronym}[ECU]
\acro{afd}[AfD]{Alternative für Deutschland (political party in the German ``Bundestag'')}
%....
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Input file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%   Zusaetzliche Pakete  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[autocite, maxlevel=3]{csquotes}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[input-symbols = ()]}

\RequirePackage[english=english-x-latest]{hyphsubst}


\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0cm, left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} 

%%%Footnotes with author (year)
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=ext-authoryear-icomp,innamebeforetitle=true,autocite=footnote,dashed=false,natbib=true,maxnames=3 ]{biblatex}
```

Editing with overleaf Comiling with XeLateX, TeX Live version 2021

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code of a *complete* document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that compiles and illustrates the problem. Moreover, it is not clear (to me, at least) what you mean by AC, and what your problem is. Is it the `'s` of the possessive case that should be added automatically (which doesn't make much sense to me)?

Comment: For your first question see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416466/, and for the second question I'm afraid the package does not have automatic sorting

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks I will look this up.